# Laravel 5.3, PHP, filter an object of arrays by string

Tags: php, laravel

I have this object `$data` :

```
{#792 ▼
  +"cities": array:346 [▼
    0 => {#454 ▼
      +"name": "XXX"
      +"id": "1"
    }
    1 => {#452 ▼
      +"name": "ABC"
      +"id": "2"
    }
    1 => {#452 ▼
      +"name": "ABC"
      +"id": "2"
    }
    2 => {#433 ▼
      +"name": "XYZ"
      +"id": "3"
    }
etc...
```

And a string (a `text` value in the DB) like `1,3`.

I want to filter the object with the object that contains that id in the string.

I was thinking to create a collection from `$data`, then an array from the string:

```
$dataC = collect ($data);
$array = explode(',', $string)
```

Create an empty collection and iterate the $dataC, and foreach value from the $dataC that has any of the values from $array, push it to the new empty collection. But for that, I need 2 chained foreachs. Is there a way that I can filter better the object with the values from the first string?
Then iterate the array, and for each

Comment: Please provide more details. Where's the code containing the two "chained foreachs"? Why not filter such data on the database level?

Comment: I'm coding right now whtat I put in the question, but I want to know if there's a better way. I'm using an external API, can't modify data from db.

Comment: `cities` is an array already, so you should be able to simply use `array_filter` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to take advantage of [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) methods itself.

```
$dataC = collect($data);
$filtered = $dataC->whereIn('id',explode(',', $string));
$filtered->all();
```

Use [whereInStrict()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-whereinstrict) if you want to strictly compare them with types.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should explode your DB string to get an array of IDs.

After that you can simply use the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to get the matched cities only:

```
$ids = explode(',', $idsString);

$cities = array_filter($data->cities, static function($city) use ($ids) {
    return in_array($city->id, $ids);
});

var_dump($cities);
```